# Can iOS class library have a font resource?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have an iOS class library `myClassLibrary` added as a reference to my iOS app `myiOSApp`:

```
MyiOSApp.sln
  myiOSApp.csproj
     References
         myClassLibrary
  myClassLibrary.csproj
```

I want to add a font file to the `myClassLibrary`:

```
myClassLibrary.csproj
 Resources
  MyFont.ttf (BundleResource)
```

In the `myiOSApp`, I have in my Info.plist the following:

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>MyFont.ttf</string>
</array>
```

But trying to load the font doesn't work:

```
var font = UIFont.FromName(fontName, size);
```

If I include the font file directly in the iOS App then the font loads correctly so I know I have the name correct.

Comment: Did you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing as you and it works on my side.

I uploaded my sample here: [custom-font-xamarin.iOS](https://github.com/XfHua/custom-font-xamarin.iOS) so that you can refer.

Refer: [using-custom-fonts-with-xamarin-ios](https://mallibone.com/post/using-custom-fonts-with-xamarin-ios)